# Select rows based upon the existence of determined amount of rows from other query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table structure (and data example):

```
Table1                   Table2
id  labelname labelvalue CustId labelname labelvalue
1   x         c1         cust1  b         xx 
1   y         c1         cust1  x         c1
1   a         c2         cust1  y         c1
2   y         c1         cust1  a         c2
2   a         c2         cust2  a         c3
3   a         c2         cust2  x         c1
4   j         c3         cust3  j         c3
```

Two tables. I try to accomplish the following output:

```
id  CustId
1   cust1 (because cust1 has the right labels (x,y,a) with the right values)
4   cust3 (because cust3 has the right labels (j) with the right values
```

Customer cust2 on the other hand is not selected because cust2 has two labels (a and x) and there is no Id with those specifications.
I have tried almost every combination of where, exists, not exists and even while constructions, but it looks like my problem is that the data is not predictive.

Comment: Please _show_ us what you tried. We'll help you fix it.

Comment: @mark_s: happy to share tryings with you, but they are on the actual data.

Comment: And again @mark_s. I have some partial solutions, do you really mean that a past the code in here? They all doesn't lead to a solution.

Comment: How do you match values between tables? Just `labelname`, just `labelvalue`, both, something else?

Comment: I join @HABO 's question. Your question doesn't properly define your problem. In the end of the day, you are trying to find a subset of values in another subset. But *WHAT* are you trying to find? If it were just name/values that exist in both datasets, then I'd use a `UNION ALL` + `GROUP BY` + `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, but the thing is that you need to define what **binds** your two data sets. I'm sure it's clear to you that you need a certain result, but your question can be interpreted in multiple ways.

Comment: It is more complex then I suggested in the example. Maybe this is missing in my original question: The data in table 1 are selection criteria and those criteria must all be met in table 2 before selection a t1.id-t2.custid combination.

Comment: You should edit your question, not just hide "clarifications" in the comments. I don't suppose there is an explanation as to why `2`/`cust1` and `3`/`cust1` don't appear in your sample output. Don't they meet all of the `Table1` criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces results that vary slightly from your accomplished output, but lacking a precise definition of your actual process it is difficult to provide a precise solution. Since your query remains classified there is no possibility to glean any clues from it.

The query finds pairs of `Table` `Id` and `Table2` `CustId` where all of the `Table1` rows for the `Id` have matching `LabelName`/`LabelValue` pairs for a `CustId` in `Table2`.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Table1 as Table ( Id Int, LabelName VarChar(10), LabelValue VarChar(10) );
insert into @Table1 ( Id, LabelName, LabelValue ) values
  ( 1, 'x', 'c1' ), ( 1, 'y', 'c1' ), ( 1, 'a', 'c2' ),
  ( 2, 'y', 'c1' ), ( 2, 'a', 'c2' ),
  ( 3, 'a', 'c2' ),
  ( 4, 'j', 'c3' );
select * from @Table1;

declare @Table2 as Table ( CustId VarChar(10), LabelName VarChar(10), LabelValue VarChar(10) );
insert into @Table2 ( CustId, LabelName, LabelValue ) values
  ( 'cust1', 'b', 'xx' ), ( 'cust1', 'x', 'c1' ), ( 'cust1', 'y', 'c1' ), ( 'cust1', 'a', 'c2' ),
  ( 'cust2', 'a', 'c3' ), ( 'cust2', 'x', 'c1' ),
  ( 'cust3', 'j', 'c3' );
select * from @Table2;

-- Run the query.
select T1.Id, T2.CustId
  from @Table1 as T1 inner join
    @Table2 as T2 on T2.LabelName = T1.LabelName and T1.LabelValue = T2.LabelValue
  group by T1.Id, T2.CustId
  having Count( T1.Id ) = ( select Count( Id ) from @Table1 where Id = T1.Id )
```

Comment: Perfect @HABO! I have tested it on the real data and it is just what I needed.
The trick using counts to match the correct amount of selection criteria was what I didn't saw. Thanks with respect!

Comment: @J.Kruijt Is "perfect" close enough to "acceptable"? If so, you could [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. If not, how might it be improved?

Comment: @@HABO: Answer is accepted. I can found a 'button' to click on to indicate that the answer can be elevated to the status of 'accepted'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a very simple:

```
select DISTINCT MIN(Id), CustId -- T2.*, T1.* 
from Table2 T2
inner join Table1 T1 on ((T1.labelname = T2.labelname) and (T1.labelvalue = T2.labelvalue))
group by CustId
```

... and I'm guessing the reason you thought it wasn't working is likely because you have overlooked your data where in fact cust2 **would** be selected because x with c1 **does** exist in Table1! Make that a non matching c999 instead and you will get exactly the result you are asking for.

Comment: thanks for trying, but the outcome is not correct. It selects an t1.id - t2.custid combination when one of the conditions in table 1 is met in table 2. It only should select rows from table 2 when the conditions in table 1 are all met.

Comment: That's a new requirement then, not previously made clear in the post. You'll likely benefit from CROSS APPLY or at least a CTE, but should be poss as the data is finite. 'fraid I don't have (unpaid) time for changing specs though.